# Pandas Pivot table - How filter a table based on another pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pivot-table

Consider the following dataframe:

[image]

Now, I am able to create these two pivot tables:

[image]

Where:

1. In the first table, I hide the value lower than 3
2. In the second one, I hide the value lower than 5.

Now, is it possible to hide in the first table, the value that are hidden in the second one? Thus, to connect the first table at the second one? This is my expected output:

[image]

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
df = {
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11,12,13,14],
    'Color': ['Green', 'Red', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red'],
    'Part': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B','A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    'Value': [10, 20, 20, -20, -10, 10, -5, 8, 9, -10,20, 20, -20, -10]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
display(df)

y = "Value"
r = df['Part']
c = df['Color']
pivot = np.round(pd.pivot_table(df, values=y, 
                                index=[r], 
                                columns=[c], 
                                aggfunc=[np.mean]),4)

pivot = pivot.style.applymap(style_negative, props='color:black;')\
      .applymap(lambda v: 'opacity: 20%;' if (v < 3) else None)
display(pivot)

pivot2 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='ID', 
                                index=[r], 
                                columns=[c],
                                aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique)


pivot2 = pivot2.style.applymap(style_negative, props='color:black;')\
      .applymap(lambda v: 'opacity: 20%;' if (v < 5) else None)


display(pivot2)
```

Comment: Try: `pivot.mask(pivot2.lt(5) | pivot.lt(3))`

Comment: Hi @enke, thanks for the answer! Is it possible to have an automatic code for different situation? Because I need to repeat this process for other pivot, with a for loop